# C# scripting from C++?

Tags: c#, c++, scripting

Is there any C# interpreter that can be used inside C++ and yet still allow .Net access?
I want to use C# scripts for games and I'm not sure how to proceed with that.

Comment: Use System.CodeDom.  An AppDomain if you need to be able to unload the scripts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a simple class in C#, let's call it `ScriptRunner` that would take your C# code as input, compile it at runtime to produce a new assembly in memory, then it will use Reflection to load a specific Type from this new assembly, and will run some method with an expected name.

Then, use COM Interop (for example) to create a `ScriptRunner` .NET object from your C++ native application, and you'll be able to use it to run scripts.

Start with:

```
var myProvider = Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider.CreateProvider();
var myCompiler = myProvider.CreateCompiler();
```

and it's really easy to continue on your own by using IntelliSense to see what's on the `ICodeCompiler` interface.

If you've got some specific questions about this approach please ask.

Comment: Lovely! I was looking exactly for this!
I didn't not want to mix other scripting language, and have one unified language!

Answer (score 2):

C# is not an interpreted language, it is a compiled language.

You *can* write C# scripts, but why not use Python or Ruby or Lua or some other true-blue scripting language?

I feel somewhat dirty mentioning this, but it looks like there is an [ECMA compliant C# scripting engine](http://www.csscript.net/).

Comment: These are thin lines.  C# is interpreted on .NET Micro.  Python, Ruby and Lua are compiled.  There are jitters for Python and (I think) Ruby.

Comment: Some people just really like C#'s syntax. I much prefer languages that use curly brackets anyway, though I do get your point. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe C# is a compiled language only.  Your best bet would be to call the csharp compiler (csc.exe) and load the assembly dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can have .net dlls and use them in your C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

Is it C++ or C++/CLI? If it's the "normal" C++ I don't think it will be possible to use C# as it is a compiled language and a managed one, your best bet would be to use the managed version of C++ and compile the C# code, then load it.

Comment: You can always use a C++/CLI wrapper dll to access .NET from a straight native C++ app.

Comment: At the time of this comment, c++/CLI was on windows only.
If you want a cross platform solution, you need something else.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried to do that but I think C# is definitely not a suitable language for scripting, for your purpose Lua or Python (for example) are certainly better...

Comment: I've implemented lua in another game but it doesn't feel right. I'd be much more comfortable with C#

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to use C++ for DirectX/OpenGL support and then want to load in the entire .Net Framework on top of that to support scripting?  That would be a very heavy footprint if it were possible.  Since C# is compiled into bytecode (just like Java), you would have to precompile your scripts.

Your best best is to to use an opensource scripting language (php, lua, etc).